# Bundle all local transient Swift Packages into a single xcframework

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I am developing a SDK and use SPM to modularise my code. All code is written in Swift.

My project structure is like this:

```
SampleApp (Workspace) -> SDK (SPM) -> ModuleA (SPM)
```

I can build and run the sample app locally successfully.

Now I want to archive/build the SDK package into a dynamic xcframework that my other clients can just drag and drop into their Xcode to consume.

I'm using `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` for that purpose and can successfully build a `sdk.xcframework` file.

But in a separated sample app where I embed the `sdk.xcframework` there, when import `SDK` module, I get this error

```
No such module 'ModuleA'

Failed to build module 'SDK' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
```

I assume here, this is because the compiler can't find `ModuleA`

Is there anyway that I can bundle the ModuleA into `sdk.xcframework` statically, so that my clients can just drag only `sdk.xcframework` into their projects to consume the SDK module?

The question is pretty much: How can I bundle ModuleA and SDK into a single .xcframework for distribution